# C++ SFML Debug Speed

Tags: c++, debugging, optimization, sfml, frame-rate

I'm working on porting my 2D platformer from XNA to SFML (C# to C++). SFML has been fine to work with so far, but I've recently encountered a problem. The release framerate is roughly 45 as where on XNA it used to be 300+ on debug, and on SFML's debug, it is not even 10. It is untolerably slow and is affecting the way my game's methods work due to how slow it is running. Why is it so slow? What is the problem?

Comment: What compiler, and what options?

Comment: Looks like you went too fast for transition from C# to C++, or your code isn't well formed. Did you try to bench your program ? Are you doing some heavy task during the main loop, like reloading textures or whatever ? Investigate these and maybe post some code.

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio Express 2012 with all settings out of the box. If I comment out my main loops, I still only run at a pathetic 12 FPS.

Comment: Are you using `std::vector`?

Comment: I am; one to store all the entities in the game, and one to store all the tiles.

Comment: Probably a large portion of the problem. There are settings for debug iterators, which also affects things like `operator[]`. 

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh697468.aspx

Comment: how can i optimize their debugging, then? how do I go about changing the values as in the link you provided?

Comment: What have you left once you commented your 'main loops' ? Your frame can't take like 100ms by doing nothing. Also it is true that vectors are very slow in debug configuration but it doesn't really explain the 45 fps in release.

Comment: I figured it out with the help of the SFML IRC channel; it was a very stupid oversight by me! I was reloading textures from files every single frame.

Comment: Aha, exactly what I told you :p.